# Sending email from html form using php

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Ive been trying this out the whole day but I cant figure out how to send an email from my html contact form containing the information from the form to my email address. Im new to php.

Ive tried running this by uploading it to free web hosting. I get the message "success!" when I press the submit button on my html form but no email is actually sent.

Any help is appreciated.

PHP script:

```
<?php

//Subject
$subject ="Contact Form Submission";

// Name
$name =$_POST['InputName'];

// Message
$message =$_POST['InputMessage'];

//Mail of Sender
$email =$_POST['InputEmail'];

//From
$header = "From:$name<$email>";

$send_contact=mail("myemail@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$header);

//Check if mail was sent
if($send_contact){
echo "Success!";
}
else {
echo "Error!";
}
?>
```

EDIT: Figured it out after one whole day of trial and error. The problem was with the free web host I was using. Changed hosts and the code started working fine. Hope this helps someone in the future. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: You still didn't figure it out?

Comment: @Bisquitue still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a pretty good idea why your code is not working. It happened to me a long time ago. The reason why your code is not working is because :

- When you pass "from" in headers, php expects an existing email account of your
  server. **For example :** `$headers = 'From: emailacc@yourserver.com';`
- So first thing you gotta do is create an email account on your server. And then put the `From` in `header` to the email address that you've just created.
- The `From` field in the `$headers` is not the `From` as you think.
- `<?php`
- `$email = $_POST["InputEmail"];`
- `$subject = $_POST["InputSubject"];`
- `$message = "From: ".$email.", ".$_POST["InputMessage"];` // you put the email address from the input form here
- `$headers = 'From: emailacc@yourserver.com';` // here is the email address specified from which u want to send the email.(i.e. your server email address)
- `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)`
- `?>`

I'm sure this will do the job :)

Comment: Hi! Your explanation makes perfect sense. I copied exactly what you said. Created an email account with my free web hosting provider. I tested out the script but an email still was not sent out. But the thing is that I could send out an email from emailacc@myserver.com to my gmail address but not from my php script. Any ideas?

Comment: Do a little test :

firstly before using form values test this (with strings):
`

$email="anymail@gmail.com";

$to = "youremail@gmail.com";

$subject = "test subject";

$message="test message";

$headers = 'From: emailacc@yourserver.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

`
do not change anything above. just copy and paste and replace only $to variable with your gmail account and **emailacc@yourserver.com**. If that works then the problem is  solved in your php script.

Comment: Ok I just copied and pasted exactly what you said and still no email was sent out. Updated my first post with the PHP script that I used and with the HTML form code. I really cant figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: OKay See,

[here](http://moodbnao.com/Capture.PNG)

i have gmail  : **pawansharma3303@gmail.com**
and server mail address : **info@botsystems.in**

this script works

Comment: I have the exact same thing but its not working for me i dont know why. Im using 000webhost. Could i be a problem on their side?

Comment: 000webhost has quite a good reputation.

So,, can you  show up exact code that you are using , including the email addresses that you are using??

Comment: Wow the problem was actually with 000webhost. I changed hosting provider and it worked immediately! Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Great!! your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Have a shot at this.

I changed you're `$header` variable around a little bit, so that rather than setting the email as *"**$email**"*, It'll actually pass through the posted email entered in the form. This apply's to the name too.

I also made it so that you pass the mail function through the parameters of the `if` statement, rather than setting a new variable.

```
$headers = "From: " . $name . "<" . $email . ">"; // notice new concatenation

if(mail("myemail@gmail.com", "Contact Form Submission", $message, $headers)){
    // success message
} else {
    // error message
}
```

Really hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi i tested it out and it still doesnt seem to be working unfortunately. Do you have any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding spaces after the "=" that might be the problem,

If that doesn't work you could try to use this

```
 <?php
     $emailvariable = $_POST['InputEmail']


    $to      = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = "Form"
    $message = $_POST['InputMessage'];
    $headers = "From: $emailvariable";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i tried using your solution but still no email sent. I really cant seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: Are you hosting your website with a domain etc.. Because if you aren't you are not able to use a mailserver to send mail. So with wamp or mamp you are not able to do this, if you are hosting it on a website try removing the uppercase letters from the $_POST['InputEmail']

Comment: Yup im hosting it on a website with a domain name using a free webhost. Do you mean something like $_post['inputemail']?

Comment: Yes else try to change message to some type of string like "messagegoeshere" and then do the same for $headers = "From: mail@example.com"