# Html form to my gmail id

Tags: html

Is it possible that I can receive form on my gmail id. I have created a form in html and I want to submit this form to my gmail id.

Hhere my code:

```
<label for="ContactFormQuantity"><strong>Quantity (Tons) </strong></label>
<input type="Number" id="ContactFormBirthday" name="contact[Quantity]" placeholder="Quantity" required>

{% assign name_attr = 'contact.form.name' | t | handle %}
<label for="ContactFormName" ><Strong> Name </Strong> </label>
<input type="text" id="ContactFormName" name="contact[{{ name_attr }}]" placeholder="Please Enter your Name" autocapitalize="words" value="{% if form[name_attr] %}{{ form[name_attr] }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.name }}{% endif %}">

<label for="ContactFormEmail"> <Strong> Email</Strong> </label>
<input type="email" id="ContactFormEmail" name="contact[email]" placeholder="Please make sure your email address is entered correctly." autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" value="{% if form.email %}{{ form.email }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}">

{% assign name_attr = 'contact.form.phone' | t | handle %}
<label for="ContactFormPhone" class="label--hidden">{{ 'contact.form.phone' | t }}</label>
<input type="tel" id="ContactFormPhone" name="contact[{{ name_attr }}]" placeholder="{{ 'contact.form.phone' | t }}" pattern="[0-9\-]*" value="{% if form[name_attr] %}{{ form[name_attr] }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.phone }}{% endif %}">  
<label for="ContactFormMessage"><Strong> Message</Strong> </label>
<textarea rows="10" id="ContactFormMessage" name="contact[body]" placeholder="Enter Product Details and other specific requirements to rceive an accurate quote.">{% if form.body %}{{ form.body }}{% endif %}</textarea>

<input type="submit" class="btn right" value="{{ 'contact.form.send' | t }}">

{% endform %}
```

Comment: please be more specific and I think you mean an API type.

Comment: [https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/] refer this link for gmail api

Comment: For @AnkitSingh  sir, main problem is- i have created a from using html, form structure is name, email id, phone no, message . i want when custome fill the form and click on "send" button, all the information i have recieve on my gamil id?

Comment: ok you can use the backend to send a mail to your email id, you have to also use php and you can refer to [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927980/using-html-and-php-to-send-form-data-to-an-email) you have just make some changes to destination email.

Comment: @AnkitSingh sir, I read it provided link. can't understand.i think sir i have to provided few links in this code <input type="submit" class="btn right" value="{{ 'contact.form.send' | t }}">

{% endform %} any solution? just receive fill form value in my gmail account. it's a quotation form , which custom fill and i will reply through  my gmail.